# Issues with voltage spikes on buck converter design

Tags: power-electronics, buck, solar-charge-controller

I am building a buck converter that I eventually plan on using in an MPPT charger.

I have not taken any power electronics courses.

Below is the spice model I’ve been using.

The issue is that point A experiences massive voltage spikes (shown as V(n009) in the simulation graph.) This issue persists regardless of the drivers (further down.) Thoughts and/or advice?

[image: Buck Circuit]

[image: Output Waveform]

[image: Simpler Buck Circuit (no FET driver)]

Comment: Why do you have a diode in series with the input supply? If the inductor current goes negative that will cause a large voltage spike .

Comment: What are nodes V(n009) and V(n010) on the schematic?

Comment: @JohnD: This diode is placed to prevent current from flowing back into the supply (solar panels in the final application of this circuit). Do you have advice in preventing this?

Comment: @Andyaka: V(n009) is indicated as "A", and V(n010) is indicated as "B" on the spice diagram. Sorry for not being clear on that.

Comment: My Dog that diagram is hard to read! Please draw diagrams as the rest of us do so we can read it.

Comment: If you have to prevent current from flowing back into the supply, and you might have negative current in the inductor, you can place enough bulk capacitance after the diode to absorb the energy without avalanching the FETs.  (You need capacitance there anyway).

Comment: Lack of input capacitor? Probe the input node. You need dead band between your MOSFETs.

Comment: @restless_resistor you can name nodes and, that is encouraged to prevent queries like this.

Comment: Just an FYI. If you are connecting a solar panel directly to a buck converter, you will need a bulk capacitor between them for efficiency. Buck converter draws current intermittently, while with solar panel, any power not drawn instantaneously is lost. You could use a boost or a Cuk converter, IIRC, to draw current continuously or use a bulk capacitor to store energy between draws by the buck.

Comment: I can't extract the data from your sources syntax but you need to insert a deadtime between the drive signals so that overlap does not exist when controlling the transistors. Also, in a CCM operation, the freewheel diode is hard switched so I don't know how the low-side MOSFET body diode is modeled but it could be the source of the issue. Try to temporarily remove the low-side MOSFET and drop in a good Schottky diode to check if the issue is still there. Then bring the MOSFET back in parallel.

Comment: What you call point A is traditionally called the switch node, or labelled SW.

Answer (score 5):

It's a synchronous buck regulator and, to operate them correctly, neither of the two MOSFETs are allowed to conduct at the same time so, when the lower MOSFET is conducting and it switches off, the stored energy in the inductor has to go somewhere.

Normally it flows through the body diode of the upper MOSFET and dumps charge into the input capacitor (an efficient and desirable action) but, you have a blocking diode and, that current has got nowhere to go and produces a massive voltage surge that is only limited by the parasitic capacitance of the lower MOSFET (the one that has just switched-off) and, the breakdown voltage of the undesirably placed blocking diode.

[image]